# pandas count number of filled cells within row

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a large dataset with columns labelled from 1 - 65 (among other titled columns), and want to find how many of the columns, per row, have a string (of any value) in them. For example, if all rows 1 - 65 are filled, the count should be 65 in this particular row, if only 10 are filled then the count should be 10.

Is there any easy way to do this? I'm currently using the following code, which is taking very long as there are a large number of rows.

```
array = pd.read_csv(csvlocation, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

for i in range (0, lengthofarray)
    for k in range(1,66):
        if array[k][i]!="":
            array["count"][i]=array["count"][i]+1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What does this have to do with `pandas`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my array is a pandas dataframe -- I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way through pandas do this rather than through an elementwise iteration

Comment: Then **please provide a [mcve]**. That is a requirement for a question to be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of the post and the subsequent comments, you are interested in knowing the number of strings in each row for columns labels 1 through 65. There are two steps, the first is to subset your data down to columns 1 through 65, and then the following is the count the number of strings in each row. To do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('abdecde'),
                   'col2': np.random.rand(7)})

# change one val of column two to string for illustration purposes    
df.loc[3, 'col2'] = 'b'

# to create the subset of columns, you could use 
# subset = [str(num) for num in list(range(1, 66))]
# and then just use df[subset]

# for each row, count the number of columns that have a string value
# applymap operates elementwise, so we are essentially creating 
# a new representation of your data in place, where a 1 represents a 
# string value was there, and a 0 represent not a string.
# we then sum along the rows to get the final counts
col_str_counts = np.sum(df.applymap(lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x, str) else 0), axis=1)

# we changed the column two value above, so to check that the count is 2 for that row idx:
col_str_counts[3]
>>> 2

# and for the subset, it would simply become:
# col_str_counts = np.sum(df[subset].applymap(lambda x: 1 if isinstance(x, str) else 0), axis=1)
```

Comment: I was hoping to count the number of _columns_ that have a string value within a particular _row_ instead - I think your logic should work for this? 
Also, I don't want to count all of the columns, only the ones labelled 1 - 65. Would that be easy, or is the best method to create a separate dataframe with the other columns dropped and count it

Comment: to simply count columns that have a string value, you can use df.select_dtypes(include=['O']).shape[1] - even if a column has numbers mixed with strings, it will still be counted - just apply that to the subset of columns you are interested in.

Comment: And no - you don’t have to create a separate data frame. I’ll update the answer to show the subset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unless I'm using this wrong, it gives me the shape of the total dataset. E.g., the output was (260,65).

I was hoping to add a 66th column to my dataset, which counts from 0 - 65 how many of the columns within the row are filled -- does that make sense?

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I'm running it: 'Series' object has no attribute 'select_dtypes', although when I run type(array) I get pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Ok as others mentioned, you should definitely check out the requirements of a minimal post to avoid this back and forth but based on your comments, I updated the answer. You now will have the number of strings in each row. So if two columns have strings for a row, the output for that row index will be 2.

Comment: @Anant I would also specifically make sure your values are being represented as strings instead of unicode. If it is unicode, just swap out str in isinstance to unicode.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and putting in the time!!

I replaced the 'isinstance' with x!="", and now it works perfectly.

Apologies if my question wasn't clear -- still trying to get the basics of python down!

Comment: @Anant No problem - happy to help and glad to hear it worked out.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to adapt your problem to this example

Say we have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["","foo","bar"],["","","bar"],["","",""],["foo","bar","bar"]])

     0    1    2
0       foo  bar
1            bar
2               
3  foo  bar  bar
```

Then we create a boolean mask where a cell `!=` `""` and sum those values

```
df['count'] = (df != "").sum(1)
print(df)

     0    1    2  count
0       foo  bar      2
1            bar      1
2                     0
3  foo  bar  bar      3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([["","foo","bar"],["","","bar"],["","",""],["foo","bar","bar"]])
total_cells = df.size
df['filled_cell_count'] = (df != "").sum(1)
print(f"{df}")
     0    1    2  filled_cell_count
0       foo  bar                  2
1            bar                  1
2                                 0
3  foo  bar  bar                  3

total_filled_cells = df['filled_cell_count'].sum()/total_cells
print()
print(f"Total Filled Cells in dataframe: {total_filled_cells}")
Total Filled Cells in dataframe: 0.5
```